# Use value from meta key array for use in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I have a CPT named 'Physicians', and have assigned an ACF field named `locations` to that post type — `locations` is an ACF post object field.

I also have a 'Locations' CPT and intend on displaying the Physicians that work out of that office on the single template for that post type. I'd like to use the values populated within the `locations` post object field above (via a meta query) to filter and display them.

The current setup sits within `single-location.php`

**WP Query**

```
// Assign current Location page title to var 
// Used in meta query to search for a match on 'Locations' field (per-physician)
$current_location_title = get_the_title();

// Build query based on query var values
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'physicians',
    // Filter by current location only
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'location',
            'value'   => $current_location_title,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        )
    )
));
```

Because `locations` is a post object field, I actually need to be able to drill down into that array to find the *true* meta value, which is found at `location->post_title`. How can I reach that value in the meta key parameter within the query above?

Comment: You can't. Not with WP_Query. But why do you need the title though? Can't you compare the ID to the current post ID, instead of the titles?

Comment: note that even if you could reliably do this, which you can't, `meta_query` is very slow. If you want to filter posts by X then X should be a taxonomy, in this case ideally a `location` taxonomy. In this case a `location` taxonomy could be hundreds of times faster than this `meta_query`. As for why you can't query, searching for `ten` will also match `often` `tent` etc, or even `ten` in unrelated fields stored within the same field. You can mitigate the problem somewhat, but it can't be solved and kept reliable